# Local Database fails and crashes in VS2017

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to set up a local database (Service-based Database) in my C# app. When I intially adds the database to the project, I can see it and edit tables in both VS and SSMS, but when I try to connect to it programmatically, I get this error:

```
"Cannot open database \"[DataDirectory]DATABASE.MDF\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'DESKTOP-MM6AR72\\majbom'."
```

And after that, the database is gone from both VS and SSMS.
I'm connecting this way:

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=[DataDirectory]DATABASE.MDF;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
{
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn))
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
    }
}
```

I have never tried to use databases this way, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. What I'm trying to accomplish, is a way of storing a lot af data temporarily in my app and make it searchable and editable.

**EDIT:**
I've followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/create-a-sql-database-by-using-a-designer

Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont see your credentials in the connection string, have you tried adding them there?

Comment: @JaimeDrq  they are covered by the integrated security = true.. so it logs in as the running user

Comment: `Initial Catalog=[DataDirectory]DATABASE.MDF;` that doesn't look correct. Initial Catalog should be the name of the DB you are connecting to, which I assume is just `[DataDirectory]`

Comment: @majbom Did you make the database as a sql lite? if you bring up SQL manager, do you see your database in the list?

Comment: I've added/created the database by right-clicking my project in VS > Add New Item > Visual C# Items > Data > Service-based Database. I can see the database in "Server Explorer" as a "Data Connection" and in "SQL Server Object Explorer" under "Databases". When I run the app and get the error, the database disappears from SQL Server Object Explorer, and under Server Explorer there is a red cross at the database icon.